# NSDateFormatting odd behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, formatting

I want to format a date from a string. I can do it this way:

```
NSString *str = @"Fri, 13 Jan 2012 12:25:49 +0000";
NSLog(@"String: %@", str);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *datefrom = [df dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"NSDate: %@", datefrom);
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
str = [df stringFromDate:datefrom];
NSLog(@"Formated String: %@", str);
```

But that's useless because I want to be able to format different dates. So when I do this:

```
NSString *str = [[stories objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date"];
NSLog(@"String: %@", str);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *datefrom = [df dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"NSDate: %@", datefrom);
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
str = [df stringFromDate:datefrom];
NSLog(@"String Formatada: %@", str);
```

It simply doesn't work. I checked the output for [[stories objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date"] and it's exactly the same string as @"Fri, 13 Jan 2012 12:25:49 +0000"

I compared the 2 strings to check if I wasn't reading them wrong. Here's the code I used to compare:

```
if ([[[stories objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date"] isEqualToString:@"Fri, 13 Jan 2012 12:25:49 +0000"]) {
    NSLog(@"They are the same");
}
else NSLog(@"They are NOT the same");
```

But they don't seem to be the same because I always get "They are NOT the same" as the output, even though they're visually exactly the same. Any idea?

Comment: Please say what values you're actually getting from what NSLog statements.  It looks like you're printing an NSDate object and expecting it to be formatted.  The NSDateFormatter produces (or reads) a formatted string, but the `decription` format of the NSDate (which is what you get when you log an NSDate directly and which is only intended for diagnostic dumps) will not change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a NSString because I logged `NSLog(@"Class: %@", [[[stories objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date"] class]);` and it says: NSCFString

Comment: You logged that where, after which of the above statements???  (Note that you never show where element "date" is set.  And you're using the value from that element as the source for extracting an NSDate, but you never show the result of attempting to format the date.)

Comment: Show the output from this statement:  `NSLog(@"String Formatada: %@", str);`

Comment: Here it is: `String Formatada: (null)`

Comment: So probably you never successfully parsed the incoming date.  What printed out for this line: `NSLog(@"NSDate: %@", datefrom);` ?  (In the second sequence.)

Comment: It was `NSDate: (null)` . I'm sure it's being parsed right, because I get every other data from the XML. I know I get the date because I can put it on a `Cell`'s title or subtitle. I just can't format it.

Comment: Let me understand this:  You get back null from parsing a date string and your "sure it's being parsed right"???

Comment: I'm sure it's being parsed from the XML. Because I can use it as a `Cell` title like this: `cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]`. It works perfectly, but I want to format this string. Even though `NSLog(@"String: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 12:25:49 +0000");` and `NSLog(@"String: %@", [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]);` output exactly the same, when I try to do `if ([[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"] isEqualToString@"Fri, 13 Jan 2012 12:25:49 +0000"])` the `if` is never true.

Comment: The fact remains that it's not being parsed.  Yes, you can print the original string, but the output of the parse in nil.  In terms of your compare, write a loop to compare the two character by character (use `characterAtIndex:`) and see where the mismatch is.

Comment: Thanks! The problem were these 3 blank spaces in the end of the string. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the object returned by [[stories objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date"] is an NSString and not an NSDate object? It might look the same when you log it, so the only way to tell is to check the type which you could do by logging:

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([str class]));

Answer (score 0):

If they are not the same the problem is the string not the dateFormatter.

Whats the NSLog() on this:

```
NSString *str = [[stories objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date"];
NSLog(@"String: %@", str);
```

Comment: The problem were these 3 blank spaces in the end of the string. That's why they were different for the computer but not for me. Now it's working!